# How to create the same animation for different meshes?

Tags: animation, mesh, three.js

I am trying to create the same skeleton animation from a mesh to a different mesh, which already has morph animation (shape keys were created). So I deleted the first mesh, kept the skeleton (which already has skeletal animation) and then, imported the second mesh with morph animation. I scaled, rotated and changed location of the second mesh so it fits the skeleton. Then, I did the process of rigging (I selected the mesh + shift + selected the armature, then clicked "ctrl + P" to create parenting). And it worked, the second mesh was animated according to the skeletal animation of the first mesh. Nevertheless, when I try to export this mesh to three.js as a skeletal animation (I chose pose mode, because when I choose rest mode, it gives me error), the mesh is displayed in a messy way and not with its normal shape. How can I fix this?